# How many rearrangements of an equation

Tags: combinatorics

How many different rearrangements of the equation $a-b=c+d$ are there with two terms on each side?

I count $-b+a=c+d$ and $a-c=b+d$ as different rearrangements for example, however, $b-a=-c-d$ is not as it involves multiplying both sides by $-1$.

Comment: How about $b-a=-c-d$?  Does that count too?

Comment: My guess is there are 24 as once you decide the position of $a$ on the LHS or $-a$ on the RHS (4 choices) then you have 3 choices for next one etc.

Comment: Choose the order of the letters from left to right.  Choose the sign of the first letter.  This will imply the sign of all other letters.  $4!\times 2=48$

Comment: @JMoravitz and if I don’t allow taking negatives then am I right about 24?

Comment: I suppose more clarification is needed whether you consider $a-b=c+d$ to be equivalent to $c+d=a-b$ and whether you allow $-a+b=-c-d$ and/or $-c-d=-a+b$.  You've shown that you are willing to subtract $c$ from the right side to move it to the left... I don't see why you wouldn't allow all terms to be subtracted and moved to the other side.  If you insist that $a$ is always positive in any arrangement, then yes, $24$.

Comment: No I allow the equation to be rearranged e.g. $a$ could be positive on LHS or negative on RHS

Comment: I have edited the text for clarity

Comment: There are $a-b=c+d$ and $a-c=b+d$ and $a-d=b+c$.  Everything else is an order change or swapping LHS and RHS or multiplication by $-1$. So depending on what you count, $3$ or $6$ or $12$ or $24$ or $48$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Based on your edit, here are the assumptions to my answer,

i) $a + b = c + d \,$ is same as $\, b + a = d + c$

ii) $a + b = c + d \,$ is same as $\, c + d = a + b$

iii) $a - b = c - d \,$ is same as $\, -a + b = -c + d \,$ (both sides multiplied by $-1$)

iv) But $\,a − b = c + d$ and $a − c = b + d$ are different, even though both are rearrangement of the same mathematical equation.

Keeping two variables on each side, number of ways to arrange variables

$ = \displaystyle \frac{1}{2} {4 \choose 2}$

Now we have two signs $+ \,$ and $- \,$, and there are $4$ places to assign signs to -

$\_ a \_ b = \_ c \_ d \,$ (even though the $+$ sign will not show before the first variable on both sides, it exists).

Now to make sure we do not count cases $(a - b = c - d) \,$ and $ \,(-a + b = -c + d)$ twice, we would assign signs to only $3$ places. It will cover all unique equations.

So number of ways to choose signs = $2^3$.

So total number of ways to make equations with given condition $ = \frac{1}{2} {4 \choose 2} \times 2^3 = 24$

Now please note condition $(iv)$. If we consider them the same, instead of different equations, all arrangements of $(a, b) = (c, d)$ we counted above would suffice. We do not need to count $(a,c) = (b,d)$ and $(a,d) = (b,c)$ separately. They can all be made from the arrangements of $(a, b) = (c, d)$. So in that case, we have only $\frac{24}{3} = 8$ different arrangements. They are -

$\begin{cases}
a + b = c + d \\
a + b = c - d \\
a + b = - c + d \\
a + b = - c - d \\
a - b = c + d \\
a - b = - c - d \\
a - b = c - d \\
a - b = - c + d \\
\end{cases}$

Lastly if you do not care about the order of variables in these equations, there will be only $3$ arrangements.